# 301 redirect not working when I think it is coded correctly

Tags: .htaccess

In my site's `.htaccess` file, I have:

```
Redirect 301 /?page_id=2276 http://www.orsgroup.com.au/community-newspaper/
```

When I load http://www.orsgroup.com.au/?page_id=2276 it doesn't redirect at all.

I can't see why. Can you?

**Update**: I now realise you can't redirect URLs with query strings like the above.

I added the following to the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/?page_id$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^2276$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.orsgroup.com.au/community-newspaper/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but the page http://www.orsgroup.com.au/?page_id=2276 is not redirecting with this update.

**Update2:** I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?page_id=2276$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.orsgroup.com.au/community-newspaper/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this redirects to http://www.orsgroup.com.au/community-newspaper/?page_id=2276

Comment: Just as with `RewriteRules` the `Redirect` command operates on URLs. The query part is _not_ considered part of the URL, so you cannot match against it. Your rule is _not_ "coded correctly". Read this: https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Comment: Same issue, sorry. `%{REQUEST_URI}` does _not_ contain the query string. Take a look at the official documentation, it comes with really good examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?page_id=2276 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.orsgroup.com.au/community-newspaper/? [L,R]
```

Or this :

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=2276$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.orsgroup.com.au/community-newspaper/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to remember that.